# how to save laser-scan 3D point cloud as the format of ADF(google tango Area Description File)

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango, point-clouds

the 3D point is generated by my laser-scaner, I want to save it as the format ADF,so Google Tango could use it

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is... you probably can't.

There is no information on the ADF format but in any case it uses more than the 3D points from the depth camera. If you watch the Google IO videos it shows how it uses the angular camera to obtain some image features and recognize the environment. I guess using only 3D data would be too expensive and could not use information from distant points.